# menu alignment does not look right in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am working on [this](http://www.crienenplastics.nl/design.html) webpage and it works all fine in Chrome, IE, Safari, but not 100% in FF. The alignment of the menu list is 1 px too low! I have no HTML errors in the document and I can't find the solution. I hope someone can help me, I like to have a perfect operating webpage in every browser!

*I have updatet my CSS file now with the last code suggestion from Martin Metsalu*

[HERE](http://www.crienenplastics.nl/idea.jpg) (design shot) you can see what I like to have, in all 4 browsers!

Here is the hover code:

```
#menu ul li a:hover,a:active {
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code related to the problem?

Comment: The menu's top border isn't a contiguous black line in Firefox. And On my computer, it also has different fonts in different browsers. Maybe you should look at that too.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are trying to adjust the height of your link elements in your list with padding. That alone is not wrong but you are trying to use padding in order to make the elements as large as your background image, which will cause a lot of problems since not every browser uses the same font or font-size as default font-size. Using padding + px-font-size in order to define a constant uniform height will only cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Change padding like this: `padding: 7px 12px;`

```
#menu ul li a {
    font-size:11px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    background-color: #258abe;
    font-family: Verdana; 
}
```

Comment: I've tried this one. But that didn't solve my problem. In IE, Chrome and Safari are still the same, and FF is different. I have also tried a css global reset, but that ruins my design (tables from PS). Any other ideas?

Comment: @user2851789I got it work fine in FF24 after updating padding. You must have seen Martin's answer also quite similar to mine.